# firebaseui signInSuccess redirect in callback

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

using ReactJS web, and FirebaseUI Auth.

I am attempting to create a signInSuccessUrl that includes the uid of the signed in user: `/users/${userId}`.

my assumption is that this needs to be defined in the call back, but I can't seem to make it work.

Currently, it defaults to redirecting to `signInSuccessUrl`, instead of using the callback...

any help is much appreciated!

```
const uiConfig = {

  signInFlow: 'popup',

  signInSuccessUrl: '/',

  signInOptions: [
    firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
    firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
    { provider: firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      requireDisplayName: true
    },
  ],

  // the area where i assume something is going wrong...
  callbacks: {
    signInSuccess: function(currentUser, credential, redirectUrl) {
      const userId = currentUser.uid;
      redirectUrl = `/users/${userId}`;
      return false
    },
  }
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`redirectUrl` is not what you think. It is populated with the content of `signInSuccessUrl` query parameter if it appended to the current page. It provides an easy way to get that URL at the end of the sign-in flow which is not easily obtained if you are using accountchooser.com.

To get your desired behavior, change your code to the following:

```
signInSuccess: function(currentUser, credential, redirectUrl) {
  const userId = currentUser.uid; 
  // Manually redirect.
  window.location.assign(`/users/${userId}`);
  // Do not automatically redirect.
  return false;
},
```

Comment: Thank you! That seems to have solved the issue.

I'd worked around the problem by redirecting to a holding page, which checked for `user`. If it was truthy, it redirected to `/users/${userId}`, and if not, back to the home page.

this is much cleaner though!

Answer (score 2):

`signInSuccess` has be deprecated in favor of `signInSuccessWithAuthResult`.
If you use it, you will see the following message in the console:

> signInSuccess callback is deprecated. Please use signInSuccessWithAuthResult callback instead.

So you need to do something like:

```
ui.start("#signin", {
    callbacks: {
        signInSuccessWithAuthResult: function (authResult, redirectUrl) {
            // Handle the result
            return false;
        },
    },
});
```

More documentation can be found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebaseui#available-callbacks).

Answer (score 1):

Another way is set the URL into the configuration object when you use the `AuthUI`.

```
 var uiConfig = {
    signInSuccessUrl: window.location.href,
    signInOptions: [ ... ]
 }
var ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());
ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', uiConfig);
```

Answer (score 1):

When added from the *config*  object of `FirebaseAuthUI` (like in @Daniel De León 's answer), you can provide the function as a callback to either `signInSuccess` or `signInSuccessWithAuthResult` in which case the value of `redirectUrl` is not what you think. It is a null value.

To get your desired behavior, change your code to the following:

```
signInSuccessWithAuthResult: (currentUser, credential, redirectUrl) => {
 //credential and redirectUrl are both null
 // currentUser has structure like
 // currentUser : {
 //     user: { 
 //       uid: 'asdasd',
 //       .....
 //    },
 //    additionalUserInfo: {
 //      isNewUser: false
 //    }
 // }  


  // Force not to redirect
  return false;
}
```

or

```
signInSuccess: (currentUser, credential, redirectUrl) => {
 //credential and redirectUrl are both null
 // currentUser has structure like
 //   currentUser: { 
 //     uid: 'asdasd',
 //     .....
 //   }


  // Force not to redirect
  return false;
}
```

Comment: I've used return false but I keep getting the same error